# How to pass Dapper TransactionScope across multiple method

Tags: c#, dapper, transactionscope, sqltransaction

Say I have 2 methods (A and B)

```
public void A()
{
   using (var connection = Database.GetConnectionString())
   using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
   {
       //do "A"
       tran.Complete()
   }
}

public void B()
{
   using (var connection = Database.GetConnectionString())
   using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
   {
       A(); //call "A"
       //do "B"
       tran.Complete()
   }
}
```

As you can see, method `B` need to call `A`, but both `A` and `B` already has its own `TransactionScope`, in this case, what's the correct way to pass the `TransactionScope`?

My Expectation is when method `A` is called, it will
-. BEGIN TRAN
-. DO "A"
-. COMMIT TRAN

when method `B` is called, it will
-. BEGIN TRAN
-. DO "A"
-. DO "B"
-. COMMIT TRAN

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms172152(v=vs.85)#managing-transaction-flow-using-transactionscopeoption) help you?

Comment: Method `A(TransactionScope tran=null)` if tran == null create TransactionScope else none?

Answer (score 2):

`TransactionScope` is ambient and supports logical nesting by default (aka `TransactionScopeOption.Required`); so usually you don't really need to *pass* it *anywhere* - as long as you (or Dapper) open(s) the connection inside the scope: it should be included. When two such `TransactionScope` are nested: committing the *inner* one effectively does nothing (aborting an inner one dooms the entire transaction) - committing the *outer* transaction commits the entire thing.

However, frankly I'd usually advise using explicit ADO.NET transactions instead of `TransactionScope`, and in that case you *do* need to pass it in; optional parameters are your friend there.

Additionally: note that `TransactionScope` is almost completely separate to `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT TRAN`; it is an *entirely different way of representing transactions* (since it needs to support distributed transactions over different systems - typically via either LTM or DTC).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, so with my current code, if I'm calling `B`, and it got to the line where `B` calls `A` and `A` is trying to do `tran.Complete`, it will basically do nothing because `A` IS NOT THE ROOT transaction, am I correct? Another question, with the way I did `using (var connection = Database.GetConnectionString())` in both method, is this going to be a problem? Since I basically has nested connection, meaning that if I'm calling `B`, and when `B` calls `A`, `A` will try to open a new connection.